# Wikipedia API - How to get all links from multiple pages?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I'm new to wiki api. I have read how to get all links from a specific page, and managed to do so, but in my case I need a list of links from many pages. And sending a request for each page is inefficient. This is the kind of request I use -

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=jsonfm&generator=links&gpllimit=500&redirects=true&pageids=1234

I must admit that I don't fully understand what each argument means. So -

1. How do you chain multiple pageids to 'pageids' argument? I guess that's a silly question but I didn't find any reference :\
2. Can the response point out which page owns each link?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @shay__, I'm not sure you can ask a list of links from different pages directly in one single query. I think that with a for loop you can change the "pageids" value and get all the links separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just join page IDs (or names if you use the `titles` parameter) with `|` which is in general how you make lists in the MediaWiki API. I don't think there is a way to find out which link comes from which page, though.